# PayPal seller email has changed in the admin

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, security

I believe a site I've been working on has been hacked.

Here's what I know:

1. PayPal seller address has changed to a random address
2. This is not a PayPal bug
3. Going through the logs - this wasn't changed through the Magento admin
4. No one has access to the AWS EC2 instance besides me
5. What is being changed is the row with path `paypal/general/business_account` under the `core_config_data table`
6. Chances of MySQL injection seems fairly low. I've grepped through the nginx and Varnish logs for 'select' - should I be grepping for anything in particular?

I would appreciate advice on the next steps to take as an answer.

Comment: I hope your problem  is meanwhile already solved?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl yes it was solved by re-generating the API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a very remote bug that's not easily reproducible. The fix was to re-generate the PayPal API key and set it into Magento.